# Is it OK to use the word "Tested" in an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers

Sometimes I enter code from memory without testing it.
If I do test, I include the word *Tested* because I think it adds value to know that the solution was tested.

Today a reviewer removed it twice. And I left it out.

[Handle missing data in SQL Server 2012 SELECT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31789972/3453226)

Is it OK to include the word Tested (with no formal test script).

Comment: Unless someone is *"following"* all of your posts, how will they know that's what you're doing? I would expect you to be pretty certain that all of your answers work, whether or not you've explicitly tested them! If anything, it would be more useful to make a note on the ones you *haven't* tested; I don't think *"tested"* is adding any value at all here.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Wow, no I don't test all code.  Often you cannot even create the user environment to test.

Comment: "Tested" on its own doesn't really tell me anything of value. What did you test? On what data? What was the outcome? What does this prove? How does it help the OP? If you were to answer all those questions, you could leave out the world "tested" and have a far better answer than your first revision.

Comment: I'm not sure how your comment relates to mine; I didn't suggest you *"test all code"*, just that you should be *"pretty certain"* that it works. If you can do that in your head, fair enough (I do!) My key point was that merely *asserting* that you've tested it is completely pointless.

Comment: Testing/debugging is the responsibility of the OP.  We cannot sensibly do it, for reasons already commented, and should not try.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Saying something is "tested" doesn't add any value to the answer.

Think of it as if you were conducting a scientific study. You claim to have found something new, or you have solved a long-standing problem. And then you say "it was tested". Okay, great ... but that is not enough for your work to be accepted. What exactly did you test? How did you test it? What were the results of the test? You could after all well mean "I tested it and it failed miserably". "Tested" would still be a fair statement, but the OP won't be happy.

So it's great you put in the extra effort, but at the very least inform the OP (and us) about what the results were of that effort. You'll have a far more detailed and valuable answer if you do.

Comment: Cool but the stated question is how to get a 0 returned with no rows in the table.  There was exactly one condition to test and one desired outcome.   I did leave left Tested out.

Comment: Extending "_inform the OP (and us) about what the results_" idea: Instead of just labeling something as "tested" I find that demos are better "proofs."  Actions do speak louder than words.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should believe this answer as it doesn't indicate whether its theories about including "tested" in an answer have been actually tested in practice.  Could you indicate in your answer whether you've tested these ideas to make sure that they bear out or if they're instead just your expectations of what should be done.

Comment: @Servy you should by now know that answers by this specific user are generally not to be trusted. They are usually not based on fact nor knowledge, and to even consider the notion said user may have tested anything is beyond laughable. I would generally not touch any of his contributions with a 10 foot Pole, nor do I know any Poles of such considerable height.

Comment: @Bart Good thing that the question is a yes/no question so even with no knowledge of what's going on you've got a 50% chance of guessing correctly.

Answer (score 7):

**Disclaimer:** I'm that reviewer.

---

It's simple noise, so I removed it. Better, don't add it.

You think the word *Tested* will add value because you are an high-rep user, but reputation doesn't count in these cases.

Anything in your answers is supposed to be tested because if you can't run the code in your IDE, it will still be tested by your experience!

Answer (score 5):

The word "tested" alone means nothing. You could add it to an untested solution just as easy.

Add example input and output, that proves a lot more.

On the other hand, you should make sure that code you post should compile and work as expected. You need to make it explicitly clear if you post unchecked or pseudo code.

Comment: Say tested if it was not would be lying

Comment: @Frisbee and of course users of Stack Overflow are incapable of lying.

Comment: Assuming honesty from someone on the internet (or rather, anywhere) is naive.

Comment: Well I don't lie

Comment: My hips don't either, but that doesn't change the fact that you must verify everything that you pull off from anywhere unless it is proven to be a consistent source of correct information.

Comment: By the way I'm very against including phrases like "tested" or "works", because in most cases where such a claim is made, the code is easily broken by providing input just outside the scope of OP's example input. Then you're down to _"This works for this one specific case "_, in which case you should instead of that just post your example input and output.

Comment: @Frisbee There isn't any context, just saying "tested" provide no value. If you want to say you tested it simply provide how you did so. Such as: *"For example with this input you get this output"*. Just saying *tested* means nothing, you didn't provide any test. I've always tested my answers, but there isn't a point in saying "tested", if it doesn't work someone will say so or it will be down-voted.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek No context?  I have rep of 20K and mainly TSQL - that is context.  If that is not context then why have rep on SO?  If I give TSQL to coworker tell them tested versus not they have context.

Comment: @Frisbee reputation is just a number. It doesn't make you free of errors or guarantee that every post you write is correct. Sure, your coworker may believe your authority, and they can blame you if you tell them to run some code and it doesn't work; here on the internet you need to prove time and again that the code you post is correct. The word "tested" does not prove that.

Answer (score 1):

Adding 'untested', when appropriate, makes more sense.  It signals to the OP that the code posted is a suuggestion for a solution and s/he should not moan about obvious typos etc. which, though strictly making the code unuseable, take little away from the value of the answer and are easily corrected.