# Review banned for trying to edit out spammy link

Tags: support, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I've been review banned over [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18936708). The user appears to have posted a valid answer, but also included a spammy "like and subscribe" signature.

[image: original answer, now deleted]

It seemed to me that editing out the signature would be one way to handle this.

I've reviewed thousands of posts over the years, so this is hardly my first "failed" audit. But a two-day ban seems draconian here.

Comment: Afaik, failed audits don't expire. The ban is just how the system works. That said: Never edit out spam. Always flag it. editing out will prevent future visitors from seeing the spam and will thus prevent more spam flags.

Comment: @Cerbrus: it is not a spam answer, and not a spam link. It is more like a *signature*, which [should be edited](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363528/2564301) (all out or to not-a-signature text).

Comment: Meh, I'd call it borderline spam, then... But okay

Comment: Screenshot for the rep-impaired among us?

Comment: @Cerbrus: so now Jon B will only get a borderline ban?

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me this is yet another edge case that should be jettisoned from the audit pile.

Comment: It's probably better when seeing posts structured as the example you've shown to err on the side that they're not signatures and are indeed trying to spam a link (it's more likely than not and this was definitely the case here btw looking at their other posts) - I can however see in isolation that it could be a valid answer with a signature that could be removed - I've lifted the review ban.

Comment: @usr2564301 But this *was* a spam answer.  It *wasn't* just some signature.

Comment: @usr2564301 - If you look at the dates from the answer (Feb '18) versus the last edit from the question (Jun '15) it should be evident that the answer just uses the post as context in order to share their spam link without actually attempting to create an answer.

Comment: 3rd party link = possible audit, especially if it's going anywhere other than to official documentation or a runnable example.

Comment: I like how some of you are still trying to overanalyze this even after I dismissed it as yet another edge case. Never change, meta.

Comment: @BoltClock people seem to agree that it was a poor audit - they rather insist that discussed post is indeed thinly veiled spam. Bad for audits, yeah and maybe not enough clear cut for a canned spam flag but still

Comment: @BoltClock So just because you think something it means no one else is allowed to think anything else?  Why are other people not allowed to have different opinions than you?

Comment: @Servy People are allowed to share their opinion on Meta. For example, that's what BoltClock did in his last comment.

Comment: @BoltClock If the audit system picks up "edge cases" with some regularity, then there's a problem with how it's picking posts to make audits out of.

Comment: @jpmc26: That much is certain.

Answer (score 30):

The link is clearly self-promotion unrelated to the code-only answer above, so it's either spam or at least candidate for deletion.

The audit system is kind of binary: if you try to edit a spam/audit answer to improve it, you fail the audit. The system considers this post as unsalvageable, so no editing can improve it.

In your case that was already bad post because of the code-only answer, so definitely worth a "Skip" or "Delete" (a code-only answer *is* an answer, so it's debatable that it deserves deletion).

But there are other more elaborate spam answers where the spammer posts generic blurb about the technology followed by a link (so the answer appears "normal", and not "link only").

Since you're not specialized in that technology, you could believe that this is a valid answer. That happened to me, and when I wanted to edit the dead links out, I got slapped by the audit system.

So when an audit presents an unclear answer or code-only answer, followed by link(s), at minimum follow the link to the answer to check if it's an audit (this isn't cheating the audit system), skip or delete, but *never try to edit the link out*.

Comment: While I agree with you, I think that the prevailing notion is that code-only answers shouldn't be deleted in LQP review.

Comment: yes, I used to delete them, but now most of the time I skip them. But a code-only answer with a spammy link is clearly crossing the line and should be deleted.

Comment: Notably, code-only answers are discouraged but not a reason by itself to delete. The normal way to deal with a code-only answer is to leave a comment asking the poster to clarify how the posted code works and how it solves the problem. Optionally accompanied with down-votes.

Comment: yes. It's strange they get flagged in the first place. I'm wondering if it's an automatic flag or a manual flag.

Comment: @yivi You shouldn't be deleting the answer for being code only (because that indeed isn't grounds for deletion).  The post is spam, and it merits a spam flag (which, if it weren't already deleted, would indeed put it on the path to deletion).

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Once upon a time it was mostly automated flags (they simply match a lot of the heuristics that also match *real* delete-worthy posts).  But as so many people have been seeing them in the queue so much they've come to the (incorrect) conclusion that they should be deleted, so people started flagging them, making the problem worse.  Had the automated system not had them as false positives I suspect we'd see a lot fewer flags of such posts.  But, sadly, a lot of users consider the "very low quality" flag just what you're supposed to click anytime a post merits a downvote.

Comment: @Servy I wasn't aware of that until recently. I believed that code only answers should be deleted. So _now_ that's a real problem for the NAA/VLQ queue. I'll spread the word, best I can do.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Servy has no sources. The community auto flags code only answer because they are low quality post since the system favors answers that solves the issue *and* explains how it does. As such, they are sent to the low quality queue to be hammered into shape or to oblivion. That's what the original design meant to do (source: the help tips of the very queue).

Comment: I believe this will remain in the gray area for a while then. For instance if someone posts a code-only answer with a lot of comments and the code is short it could be acceptable I guess. when the codeonly answer is prefixed by "try this it works for me" it cries for deletion though :)

Comment: Feel free to ignore those cries for deletion and as @Lundin says - think about leaving a comment for the answerer that their answer would be better with some explanation.

Comment: A question on code-only answers - are the valid if it's well/overly commented out, to the point of explaining all of the aspects?

Comment: noone says that a code only answer is a good answer. The comments help, but explanations before and/or after with hyperlinks on the docs, etc... or quotes of the manual is always better

Answer (score 12):

You want [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/303700) from ChrisF, a moderator.

> If, at first glance, the the post looks good but **has an apparent spam link at the end** there's a good chance that **it is really spam**.

And this hot question: [Should spam posts be edited?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110030/should-spam-posts-be-edited)

Combine those two and you'll know what you did wrong.