# Is providing a link to a consultation website, along with the answer, spam?

Tags: discussion, self-promotion

I noticed an answer, where the user answered the question and left a link to a consultation site where you book by the hour. I personally thought about editing the answer and just removing the line promoting the service, but was not sure if that would be accepted. Additionally, I doubted a spam flag would be accepted since the answer was not **just** promoting a product or service. **It obviously adds nothing to the answer, including for future readers**, and it is not just some open source software that solves the OP's problem.

> John Doe CTO at [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (click for free consultation)

[Answer with consultation link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64355869/6950859)

My question is what should I do for answers that are not **necessarily** spam, but offering a paid service on an entirely separate website for additional help? I personally think the user posting about consultation services should keep that within their profile, not on an answer.

Comment: At best, it’s noise and should be edited out. If they do it often, it should probably be flagged so a mod can let them know that that kind of self-promotion is not welcome on the site.

Comment: @yivi Ok I figured as much, I saw you edit it out soon after. I guess I was not sure if it would be accepted as a suggestion.

Comment: It seems fairly straightforward to see that this is just noise in the answer, so I'm pretty confident you wouldn't have run into issues regarding getting a suggested edit accepted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348489/consensus-on-self-promotion-and-spam

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5029/397219)

Comment: I don't disagree with the thrust of the comments here, but related: [Should editors excise signatures in answers even if they contain useful organisation information?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363528/should-editors-excise-signatures-in-answers-even-if-they-contain-useful-organisa)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Some people have already pointed this out, but if the post has valid information other than the link, you can simply edit it out and comment explaining the self-promotion policy. On the other hand, if the answer is entirely spam, flag it as spam.

If they persist in doing this even after being offered an explanation, you should mod-flag. Typically they'll start with a somewhat firmer warning, and if they still don't listen to that will likely give them a timed suspension for promotional content.